# PHP form that does GET and Post

Tags: php, clickatell

I have a form that sends a SMS via Clickatell in accordance to their HTTP api

```
<form action="http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg" method="get">
```

This works, But I need to save the SMS I send to my SQL as well. I know to send I need to use method="post"

But then this will not get the number and text I want to send and send it.

How can I make it that it gets the info from the form and also post it to the SQL.

Presuming the form is 1.php and the submit to sql is 2.php

Comment: it seems the problem would be that your action is at `clickatell.com` and not the method - this form wouldn't go to your server at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the form post all of the data, and save your text in a database, then do a cURL call to the clickatell API afterwards. Google cURL get_page function for example on how to use cURL to load a page

Comment: or use `file_get_contents()` http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: +1 This would also have the advantage of not needing to put your [Clickatell API login/password](http://www.clickatell.com/apis-scripts/apis/http-s/) in the web page which is probably the case now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$_GET['variable_name'];` in your 2.php

You can check form documentation here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use can use CURL function for more detail..
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

and store $result in database,$result is an array so use (foreach) loop for fetch data
and it also provide a response of ur api is success or fail.